# DataLoadOptions LoadWith preventing object load when relationship is null

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have a situation where I'd like to eager load the organization property of a user being retrieved from the DB using LINQ-to-SQL (because of my `using` here attempts to get the property later fail because the context's connection is closed). The problem is that sometimes the user does not have an organization. In that case `FetchUserByName` returns `null`. Not what I want at all. Is there a way to get this to work the way I want, which is to return an instance of user whether they have an associated organization or not?

```
    private static void EagerLoad(DataContext ctx)
    {
        var loadOpt = new DataLoadOptions();
        loadOpt.LoadWith<User>(u => u.Organization);
        ctx.LoadOptions = loadOpt;
    }

    public User FetchUserByName(string username)
    {
        User user = null;
        using (var ctx = contextManager.GetSingleDataContext())
        {
            EagerLoad(ctx);
            user = ctx.GetTable<User>().SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username && u.IsActive);
        }

        return user;
    }
```

Comment: There are a few threads on SO that describe how `LoadWith` creates an `INNER JOIN`, which is the cause of this problem. There are workarounds, such as described here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7639417/entity-framework-and-forced-inner-join

Comment: @RJLohan Actually, `LoadWith` creates both `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER LEFT JOIN`. But your linked question helped me track down the issue somewhat, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documenting what the fix was for others who may run into this.

`LoadWith` actually determines whether to use an `INNER JOIN` or an `OUTER LEFT JOIN` in the SQL created by LINQ-to-SQL by looking whether the foreign key in the data model class is nullable in the database. If it is nullable it uses the outer join.

```
    [Column]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; } /*** Here is The Problem ***/

    private EntityRef<Organization> _organization;

    [Association(OtherKey = "OrganizationId", Storage = "_organization", ThisKey = "OrganizationId", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Organization Organization
    {
        get
        {
            return this._organization.Entity;
        }
    }
```

Changed the one line to:

```
public? int OrganizationId { get; set; }
```

And then everything worked as expected.